mysql cte recursive to get all siblings
I'm trying to get all siblings / connections of given user_id, based on phone_id(s). My table looks like the following (ad_users_id and ad_phones_id are foreign keys of specific tables holding details about users / phones).



id
ad_users_id
ad_phones_id
date_time




90
7177
19515



125
1967
202



235
7177
19868



236
7177
19519



237
7177
19516



238
7177
19517



239
7177
20196



245
7177
19585



247
7177
19701



295
7177
19703



342
3915
19868



343
3915
19519



346
3915
19516



426
3915
19517



368
3915
20196



414
3915
19585



403
3915
19701



404
3915
19703



1707
1962
202



2124
1967
25141



2129
9329
25141




Basically I need to get all direct and indirect connections of given user_id. I managed to build a mysql query (recursive CTE) which doesn't look really clean, but looks like it also doesn't work for users with several phone_id(s), like user_id 7177.
WITH RECURSIVE connections (table_id, user_id, phone_id)
AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(ut.id AS CHAR(200)) AS table_id,
    ut.ad_users_id AS user_id,
    ut.ad_phones_id AS phone_id
  FROM ad_phones_users_taxonomy ut
  WHERE ut.ad_users_id = 7177  -- Starting user
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CONCAT(c.table_id, ',', CAST(ut2.id AS CHAR(200))) AS table_id, -- CONCATENARE pentru a evita din bucla id-urile deja trase
    ut2.ad_users_id AS user_id,
    ut2.ad_phones_id AS phone_id
  FROM ad_phones_users_taxonomy ut2
  INNER JOIN connections c ON ut2.ad_phones_id = c.phone_id OR ut2.ad_users_id = c.user_id
    WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(ut2.id, c.table_id)
        LIMIT 10
)
SELECT
  table_id, user_id, phone_id
    FROM connections

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.
Expecting to retrieve all connections (direct and indirect), but for user_id(s) with multiple phone_id(s) almost "kills" mysql server
--- later edit ---
This is the CREATE TABLE:
CREATE TABLE `ad_phones_users_taxonomy` (
  `id` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_users_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_phones_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_timp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `ad_phones_users_taxonomy` (`id`, `ad_users_id`, `ad_phones_id`, `date_time`) VALUES
(90, 7177, 19515, '2024-05-08 19:57:41'),
(125, 1967, 202, '2024-05-08 19:58:26'),
(235, 7177, 19868, '2024-05-08 20:02:52'),
(236, 7177, 19519, '2024-05-08 20:02:55'),
(237, 7177, 19516, '2024-05-08 20:02:58'),
(238, 7177, 19517, '2024-05-08 20:03:01'),
(239, 7177, 20196, '2024-05-08 20:03:04'),
(245, 7177, 19585, '2024-05-08 20:03:25'),
(247, 7177, 19701, '2024-05-08 20:03:31'),
(295, 7177, 19703, '2024-05-08 20:05:55'),
(342, 3915, 19868, '2024-05-08 20:08:21'),
(343, 3915, 19519, '2024-05-08 20:08:24'),
(346, 3915, 19516, '2024-05-08 20:08:33'),
(426, 3915, 19517, '2024-05-08 20:12:27'),
(368, 3915, 20196, '2024-05-08 20:09:36'),
(414, 3915, 19585, '2024-05-08 20:11:53'),
(403, 3915, 19701, '2024-05-08 20:11:21'),
(404, 3915, 19703, '2024-05-08 20:11:24'),
(1707, 1962, 202, NULL),
(2124, 1967, 25141, '2024-05-13 19:27:55'),
(2129, 9329, 25141, '2024-05-13 19:45:32');

For any of the user_id(s): 1962, 1967, 9329 this would be the expected outcome:



id
ad_users_id
ad_phones_id
date_time




125
1967
202



1707
1962
202



2124
1967
25141



2129
9329
25141




For any of user_id(s) 7177 or 3915, expected outcome:



id
ad_users_id
ad_phones_id
date_time




90
7177
19515



235
7177
19868



236
7177
19519



237
7177
19516



238
7177
19517



239
7177
20196



245
7177
19585



247
7177
19701



295
7177
19703



342
3915
19868



343
3915
19519



346
3915
19516



426
3915
19517



368
3915
20196



414
3915
19585



403
3915
19701



404
3915
19703





Provide complete sample (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO, desired output) with explanations.

@Catelin update your possible output according to input table

I suspect you're getting infinite recursion due to the way you're joining with the CTE.

Condition OR ut2.ad_users_id = c.user_id in join is completely unnecessary. And causes deep recursion with your test data - kills your server.  For traverse  path better CAST(CONCAT(c.table_id, ',', ut2.id )AS CHAR(200)) AS table_id

@ValNik Condition OR ut2.ad_users_id = c.user_id is used to retrieve also indirect connections. Removing the condition would stop the query to direct connections.

CREATE PROCEDURE get_all (in_user_id INT)
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (

-- anchor part - select all rows for specified user

  SELECT ad_users_id, ad_phones_id
  FROM ad_phones_users_taxonomy
  WHERE ad_users_id = in_user_id

-- use UNION DISTINCT which will remove duplicates
-- including the users which are processed/collected already

  UNION DISTINCT

-- recursive part - add siblings 
-- join one table copy by the phone then another copy by the user id
-- i.e. get a user with the same phone from t1 
-- then get all phones for this user from t2

  SELECT t2.ad_users_id, t2.ad_phones_id
  FROM cte 
  JOIN ad_phones_users_taxonomy t1 USING (ad_phones_id)
  JOIN ad_phones_users_taxonomy t2 ON t1.ad_users_id = t2.ad_users_id
  )

-- finally retrieve original rows for gathered users

SELECT DISTINCT ad_phones_users_taxonomy.*
FROM ad_phones_users_taxonomy
JOIN cte USING (ad_users_id)
ORDER BY id;

fiddle
PS. The query is placed into stored procedure which allows do not repeat the whole text avoiding misprints. You may use the query only, of course.
